# Calculating distance within zones

Tags: python

So I am doing a challenge and it requires me to calculate the distance travelled within three different zones.

Zone 1: 0 to 30km
Zone 2: 31 to 60km
Zone 3: 61 to 90km

Now assuming a car travels 34km from Zone 1 to Zone 2 (enters the highway at 24km and exits at 58km), how can I get the distance travelled in Zone 1 separately from the distance travelled in Zone 2.
This is what I have so far:

```
def determine_zone(marker):
""" (int) -> (int)
Return the zone corresponding to the marker (1,2,3) as an int.
>>> determine_zone(34)
2
>>> determine_zone(72)
3
"""
if marker >= ZONE1_BEGIN and marker <= ZONE1_END:
    return 1
elif marker >= ZONE2_BEGIN and marker <= ZONE2_END:
    return 2
elif marker >= ZONE3_BEGIN and marker <= ZONE3_END:
    return 3

distance_travelled = abs(entry - exit)

entry_zone = determine_zone
exit_zone = determine_zone

distance1 = abs(distance_travelled - ZONE2_BEGIN)
print(distance1)
```

Comment: Enters the highway from **where**? Zone 1? If not, isn't the distance in Zone 1 just 6? If you are asking a Python question, include your python code

Comment: Hey, I just added the code. I know the distance is 6 in zone one but if the distance the car travelled changes, how can I use the same code for this, for that case too?

Answer (score 0):

```
ZONE1_BEGIN = 0
ZONE1_END = 30
ZONE2_BEGIN = 31
ZONE2_END = 60
ZONE3_BEGIN = 61
ZONE3_END = 90

def determine_zone(marker):
    """ (int) -> (int)
    Return the zone corresponding to the marker (1,2,3) as an int.
    >>> determine_zone(34)
    2
    >>> determine_zone(72)
    3
    """
    if marker >= ZONE1_BEGIN and marker <= ZONE1_END:
        return 1
    elif marker >= ZONE2_BEGIN and marker <= ZONE2_END:
        return 2
    elif marker >= ZONE3_BEGIN and marker <= ZONE3_END:
        return 3

def determine_distance(point,zone,loc = None):
    if zone==1:
        distance = ZONE1_END - point if loc == 'START' else point - ZONE1_BEGIN +1
    elif zone==2:
        distance = ZONE2_END - point if loc == 'START' else point - ZONE2_BEGIN +1
    elif zone==3:
        distance = ZONE3_END - point if loc == 'START' else point - ZONE3_BEGIN +1
    return distance

entry = 24
exit = 58

distance_travelled = abs(entry - exit)

print "Distance Travelled : %s"%distance_travelled

entry_zone = determine_zone(24)
exit_zone = determine_zone(58)

## Logic to determin how much distance travelled in each zone

entry_zone_distance = determine_distance(entry,entry_zone,'START')
exit_zone_distance  = determine_distance(exit,exit_zone,'END')

print "Car Entered in Zone %s and travelled distance %s"%(entry_zone,entry_zone_distance)
print "Car Exited in Zone %s and travelled distance %s"%(exit_zone,exit_zone_distance)
#distance1 = abs(distance_travelled - ZONE2_BEGIN)
#print(distance1)
```